# Identity Server nodes as managers or manager/workers

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, wso2-identity-server

I have a question about clustering two Identity Servers together. Can both IS'es be manager nodes, or do I need to make one manager and one worker?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know (and according to the [a wso2 docs](https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/50496127)  )you don't have anything like worker node for IS

just share the databases, registry, userstore and set the cluster (use ip addresses) and you are good to go. I had both nodes as manager without any issues (and no documentation mentions setting any of nodes as a worker)